# Class Listener not inject repository

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am working on a spring boot 2.7 project where I am making an insert to a historical table for auditing, I am using the @EntityListener annotation to listen to entity events and a listener class to execute some save methods on the historical table when An insert or update is made in the table that was affected, I am facing a problem and that is that when I want to inject a JPA repository into the listener class when I do the injection with the annotation @autowired Repostory repository gives me a null point exception When the save is made to the table, I have tried various forms of injection but I don't understand why I get a null pointer.

I have the following structure in spring boot:

Entity User

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@EntityListeners(value = UserListener.class)
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;
    private String email;

    public User() {}

    public User(String name, String email) {
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

}
```

Repository

```
@Repository public interface UserHistoricalRepository extends JpaRepository < User, Long > {}
```

Class listener

```
@Component
public class UserListener {

    @Autowired
    private UserHistoricalRepository userHistoricalRepository;

    @PostPersist
    @PostUpdate
    public void saveUserHistorical(User user) {

        UserHistorical userHistorical = new userHistorical();
        userHistorical.setId(user.getId());
        userHistorical.setName(user.getName());
        userHistorical.setEmail(user.getEmail());
        userHistorical.setDateCreation(new Date());

        userHistoricalRepository.save(personaHistorico);

    }
}
```

First try with:

`@Autowired private UserHistoricalRepository userHistoricalRepository;`

I get the following error:

"Null pointer exception"

After with:

```
private final UserHistoricalRepository userHistoricalRepository;

public class UserListener(UserHistoricalRepository userHistoricalRepository) {
    this.userHistoricalRepository = userHistoricalRepository;
}
```

I get the following error:

"Relying upon circular references is discouraged and they are prohibited by default. Update your application to remove the dependency cycle between beans. As a last resort, it may be possible to break the cycle automatically by setting spring.main.allow-circular-references to true."

I added "spring.main.allow-circular-references=true" to my application.properties file but I always got the same message

The truth is that I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.